# Restrict time in jQuery timepicker dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having two fields in my form. One is date field which is using jQuery date picker and another one is jQuery time picker. Now the problem is, if i select the today's date in the date field, then the time picker should not shows the past time. For eg. if the time now is 17:00 hrs, then the timepicker should not shows the time before 17:00 hrs as selectable. Here is my code,

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate:'0'});
    $('.timepicker').timepicker();
});

$("#date").click(function(){
    if($("#date").val()=='04/17/2012')
    {
        updatetimefortoday();
    }
});![enter image description here][1]

function updatetimefortoday()
{
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
        onHourShow: timepickerRestrictHours
    });

    function timepickerRestrictHours(hour)
    {
        if ((hour > 17))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is if we call the function `updatetimefortoday()` on `document.ready`, it is showing the timepicker correctly. But if we do it on click of the date field as shown in the code it is not working.

[image]

This is the expected output after selecting the date.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have an official time-picker. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using the time picker that available here, http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After working a bit more with it, I came to the conclusion that the best way to do that is to always call the onHourShow function and validate the selected date in that function. I think this is better because the disabled hours are still visible to the user instead of blank cells.

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});
$('#time').timepicker({
    onHourShow: function( hour ) { 
        var now = new Date();
        // compare selected date with today
        if ( $('#date').val() == $.datepicker.formatDate ( 'mm/dd/yy', now ) ) {
            if ( hour <= now.getHours() ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});​
```

here is a working example :
http://jsfiddle.net/fgelinas/kUFgT/4/

As for the start and end hours problem reported by Aymad Safadi, I will see what I can do, this is definitely a bug.

Comment: Hey diddle diddle, there's something broken about this fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The timepicker is already attached to the input from the document ready function.
I think you can change the onHourShow property this way instead :

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker( 'option', 'onHourShow', timepickerRestrictHours);
```

Comment: Hi Francois Gelinas, Thanks for your answer but it is not working. I uploaded a screenshot of how it should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try @FrancoisGelinas' approach (which is the standard jQuery UI way of doing it), only use the library's options.  In this case: "hours".

Something like:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate:'0',
    onSelect: function()
    {

        if($("#date").val()=='04/18/2012')
        {
            $('.timepicker').timepicker( 'option', 'hours', {starts: 05, ends: 23});
        }
        else
        {
            $('.timepicker').timepicker( 'option', 'hours', {starts: 0, ends: 23});
        }
    }
});
$('.timepicker').timepicker();​
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/JbjLg/

That said, there seems to be a bug with the timepicker library itself. If you pick a "start" hour greater than 11, all the hours will disappear.  I would **strongly** suggest you look into this and notify the auther about it, either via email or as an issue on his [GitHub](https://github.com/fgelinas/timepicker/issues) site.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          minDate: 0
        });
        });

        $(function() {
        $( ".timepicker" ).timepicker({
            minTime: { hour: new Date().getHours(), minute: new Date().getMinutes() },
        });
        });

    </script>
```

Dont forget these:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fgelinas/timepicker/master/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div class="demo-section k-content">

                <h4>Start time</h4>
                <input id="start" value="8:00 AM" style="width: 100%;" />

                <h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">End time</h4>
                <input id="end" value="8:30 AM" style="width: 100%;" />

            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    function startChange() {
                        var startTime = start.value();

                        if (startTime) {
                            startTime = new Date(startTime);

                            end.max(startTime);

                            startTime.setMinutes(startTime.getMinutes() + this.options.interval);

                            end.min(startTime);
                            end.value(startTime);
                        }
                    }

                    //init start timepicker
                    var start = $("#start").kendoTimePicker({
                        change: startChange
                    }).data("kendoTimePicker");

                    //init end timepicker
                    var end = $("#end").kendoTimePicker().data("kendoTimePicker");

                    //define min/max range
                    start.min("8:00 AM");
                    start.max("6:00 PM");

                    //define min/max range
                    end.min("8:00 AM");
                    end.max("7:30 AM");
                });
            </script>

            <style>

            </style>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```